# Checking if a URL is valid via responcecodes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My App gets a lot of URLs back via JSON data.

Some of the URLS have no content (Code 204) and some do (Code 200).

At the moment I get the response code by making a call to the URl and the response code comes back along with all the data at that URL. So it pretty much downloads everything at the URL just so I can check its response code.

Is there a way to make a call to only get the response code and not all the data? There can be a lot of data sometimes so its slow and a waste of the users data allowance.

Many Thanks,
Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are getting content with 204 status code?

> [The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5)

For other status codes, consider using [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) method instead of GET. Off course you can not use [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) instead of POST, PUT etc. because they are supposed to modify server state so it doesn't make sense to just get metainformation for these methods.